# Disable Internet Access on Eth0

Tags: networking, network-interface, dhcp

I have a Raspberry with `eth0` (`192.168.0.2` / `static`) connected to a router (Fritz Box @ `192.168.0.1`). The Router has internet connection. The Raspberry has a mobile usb stick with `ppp` connect to the internet. Actually if `ppp` is not connected the internet access from the Raspberry is through the Router over `eth0`. If `ppp` is connected the internet access is via `ppp`. if I del the default route for `eth0` there is no internet connection if `ppp` is not connected and if `ppp` is connected internet connection is through `ppp`. So far everything fine. But if restart the raspberry it again has internet connection through `eth0`. I want to allow the raspberry internet connection only via `ppp`. `eth0` just for internal communication like ssh. Any ideas how to configure that?

`/etc/network/interfaces` looks like:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.178.2
netmask 255.255.255.0


allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to get rid of a static route. Check your `/etc/network/interfaces` file for any route configuration. Comment these lines (add a `#` at the beginning of the line), save the file, reboot, and try again.
But your Pi is more than likely getting this info via DHCP, I would suggest configuring the interface with static details (and without a route).

Comment: i get rid of the static routes. still have internet via eth0 after reboot. updated the question with /etc/network/interface content

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the Raspberry to have an connection when PPP is disconnected, remove the gateway from your network configurations. Probably you're using the file /etc/network/interfaces, so open it on a text editor and change it from

```
auto eth0
inet iface eth0 static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

to

```
auto eth0
inet iface eth0 static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    #gateway 192.168.0.1
```

You'll still able to access the raspberry on local network (192.168.0.0/24) but it won't have an internet connection if PPP is down.

Comment: thanks. i tried that.. but internet is still available in eth0. /etc/network/interfaces looks like: # Ethernet
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.178.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.178.1
#dns-nameservers 192.168.178.1

Comment: Did you rebooted after changing the file? What is the output of " route -n"

Comment: yep, output is: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     304    0        0 wwan0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0 if ppp not connected.

Comment: if ppp is connected its: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     304    0        0 wwan0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0

Comment: but when i do: route del default route -n is still Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     304    0        0 wwan0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0 but ping google over eth0 doesnt work.

Comment: Try to format your comments, they're hard to read as they are now. Apart from that, I believe there is another system managing your IP settings. Maybe wicd, or NetWork Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the default route for `eth0` with a higher metric (= lower priority) should work:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.178.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    up ip route replace default via 192.168.178.1 dev eth0 metric 1024
#                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This way if a default route with a lower metric is present, for example when `ppp0` is connected, then that one will be selected. Otherwise, this `metric 1024` one will be selected and your Pi will still have access to internet.